# How to encode images within HTML?

Tags: css, html

How can you encode a background image within your HTML? Example:

```
background-image: url(data:image/gif;base64,XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX);
```

If I have an image file, how can I encode its contents and then convert it to a string? Is this the same thing those custom font services do?

Comment: Be aware that encoding image data means the image will not be cached in the visitor's browser, which can slow down page render.  Not something terribly bad for very small images like icons, but is problematic for large images particularly on mobile devices.  If no caching is what you're going for, then disregard this.

Comment: @kevin628: Could you elaborate on that? If the CSS file is cached, wouldn't the base64 data inside be cached, too?

Comment: @pixelistik Yes, though it will still have to decode the base64 data into image data, as opposed to simply pulling from the cache.  There may not be a real performance loss in the end, but I've seen programmers and designers overuse base64-encoding in the past.

Comment: I see. Good point, although I wouldn't exactly call this "no caching".

Answer (score 4):

You can convert your image with this website:

http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64

and use it like:

(X)HTML Image Embedding Example

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" width="158" height="158" 
  src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJ4A..." />
```

CSS Image Embedding Example

```
div.image {
  width:158px;
  height:158px;
  background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJ4A...);
}
```

XML Image Embedding Example

```
<image>
  <title>An Image</title>
  <link>http://www.your.domain</link>
  <url>data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAJ4A...</url>
</image>
```

Embed other stuff!

Data URIs can potentially store any type of data, not just images! Try these examples on for size:
(X)HTML CSS Embedding Example

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
  href="data:text/css;base64,LyogKioqKiogVGVtcGxhdGUgKioq..." />
```

(X)HTML Javascript Embedding Example

```
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="data:text/javascript;base64,dmFyIHNjT2JqMSA9IG5ldyBzY3Jv..."></script>
```