# Beginner Q. about XML & XSLT

Tags: html, xml, image, xslt

Q. 1. Is it possible to put an image into an XML file?

Q. 2. If I have the following in an XML file...

flowers.jpg

How can I output this image when I use XSLT to convert my XML file into a HTML file? Would it be better to put the "src" of the image in the XML file & then use XSLT to output it? How could you do this?

Thank you!

Comment: try typing your first question into a search engine : "Is it possible to put an image into an XML file?"

Answer (score 2):

Q.1. See [How do you embed binary data in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19893/how-do-you-embed-binary-data-in-xml) (short answer, is yes).

Q.2. See [XSLT: Convert base64 data into image files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684909/xslt-convert-base64-data-into-image-files/1687218#1687218)

As to whether it would be better to use the src with an image location or not, that is completely dependent upon your implementation.  For example, does the XML file need to be essentially self contained or can it refer to additional external items.

Answer (score 1):

For most applications it's probably best to keep the images in separate files and have the XML link to them e.g. with a relative URI. Your rendering application will then need to ensure the generated HTML references the images in the right place; it's quite likely that your publishing workflow will want to move the images at the same time.

Encoding images in base64 within the XML is possible, but is unlikely to be the best choice here, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Yes; sort of.

- you can put a path to your image in the XML file, then map that to the `src` attribute of an `img` in html using xslt.
- you can embed images in your html (see [How to encode images within HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11474346/how-to-encode-images-within-html)) - so you can put this same data into your xml and then map it appropriately using your xslt.

However you cannot convert your XML to a JPG file and HTML page referencing that file - at least, not without other code (i.e. beyond XML/XSLT/HTML solutions) to do the heavy lifting.